# having issues with angular minification

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with angular minification when I release.  I've redone my controller to have annotations as recommended, but still get the same error:

Error: Unknown provider: nProvider <- n

Here's my first few lines of code for the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap.dialog']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$dialog', '$http', function ($scope, $dialog, $http){
```

UPDATE:  sorry, I found that there was another function I was using which was taking in $scope as parameter.  That was causing the issue. I basically did the same thing to annotate its parameters, and now it works.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339272/angular-js-unknown-provider?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular Control not working after minified JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545418/angular-control-not-working-after-minified-js-file)

Comment: sorry, I found that there was another function I was using which was taking in $scope as parameter.  That was causing the issue.