# Minifier confusing variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I have an angular router that uses the resolve feature and calls a service `MyService`.

```
var Router = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state(home, {
            resolve:{
                myFactory: 'MyFactory',
                checkUser: function(myFactory){
                    return myFactory.getUser().then(function(data){
                        // some logic with data
                    });
                }
            },
        });
};

module.exports = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', Router];
```

When i run it through the minifier, i end up with:

```
var e = function(t, e) {

    t.state(home, {
        url: "/home",
        resolve: {
            myFactory: "MyFactory",
            checkUser: function(t){
                return t.getUser().then(function(e){

                });
            }
        },
    })
}
;
t.exports = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", e]
```

The problem here is variables `t` and `e`.

At the top level:

```
t = $stateProvider
e = $urlRouterProvider
```

However, within my `resolve`, `t` and `e` are used again, but:

```
t = $stateProvider but should = myFactory
e = $urlRouterProvider but should = data
```

And so `t.getUser` or `t.getProducts` do not actually exist and so my app fails to load.

UPDATE:

---

Annotated version:

```
var Router = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state(home, {
            resolve:{
                myFactory: 'MyFactory',
                checkUser: ['myFactory', function(myFactory){
                    return myFactory.getUser().then(function(data){
                        // some logic with data
                    });
                }]
            },
        });
};

module.exports = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', Router];
```

Comment: I fail to see your problem. Within `resolve`, `t` is the parameter name of the `checkUser` function, so whoever calls `checkUser` is responsible to provide the correct argument.

Comment: @ammoQ - thanks for the info, nothing within the app calls checkUser, the getUser() and getProducts are called when the router is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Should have learned about angular's injection mechanism first. Found this: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 and this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di - both mention the problems arising from minification and implicit dependency annotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Control not working after minified JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545418/angular-control-not-working-after-minified-js-file)

Comment: @ammoQ I still think you were absolutely correct when writting the answer. Whoever calls `checkUser` provides the argument. Oam Psy, something calls that function otherwise you would never get anything done, and whatever calls it, gives it the value, if you just want to use the value from the line of code above, remove the "myFactory" from the list of arguments and instead use `this.myFactory` to access that object's property if the function call is being made by the object. If it is nested then you need to provide another parameter to store `this` within it.

Comment: @Dellirium This suggestion isn't valid in the context of Angular DI.

Comment: @estus that is beyond me as I am not familiar with angular, I'd write a how-would-I-do-it in the comments but it is too long, written it as answer instead, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFactory` is local dependency in this resolver. As any other dependency, it should be [annotated](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) in order to be injected properly in minified JS.

```
            checkUser: ['myFactory', function(myFactory){
                return myFactory.getUser().then(function(data){
                    // some logic with data
                });
            }]
```

[Strict mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection) may be used to avoid this kind of bugs in production.

Comment: thanks for this, i have added an Annotated update see above. When i copy that code, in to a minifier for example https://javascript-minifier.com/ the same issue occurs as per my OP in that myFactory.getUser() becomes e.getUser

Comment: @OamPsy This is normal behaviour. `e` refers to local variable and it may be used multiple times in different function contexts. It doesn't interfere with Angular DI if the function is annotated properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap. You need NG-Annotate.
For Gulp for example I used [this one.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate)

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially an issue with accessing objects and their properties from within a "method" of the object, as it is written in-properly.

I've made you a [**Fiddle Example of Object Access**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvja4r4p/) which shows how you can access objects properties and how to differentiate between accessing it's properties and the arguments passed to the functions.

To correct your particular error, your resolve would probably need to look like this, but I'd advise you to check the fiddle example and try to figgure it out yourself. I have 0 experience with angular, from what I undestand you can reference $scope there, which would act as a replacement for `this` but as I said I am not familiar, hope this helps:

```
resolve:{
            self: this,
            myFactory: 'MyFactory',
            checkUser: function(){
                return self.myFactory.getUser().then(function(data){
                    // some logic with data
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: thanks, with this i see: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from this part of the code, can you replace `//some logic with data` with a `alert("I entered here");` and verify that it is not being executed (make it be the first line of that function)? I am not sure where does angular bind it's `fn` argument to what call, but it should not be this method right here. Can you verify that the `alert("I entered here");` does not occur?

Comment: have tried the console log, nothing is logged. However, if i use my unminified version, the log appears.

Comment: And about your point of something is calling checkUser, i have just changed this to something randon like somethingRandom, and blahing... it still runs on app load

Comment: It would mean that it gets called through some key most likely. Point is, in order for any of your code within to work it has to be called, regardless of name, it is a dead method if nothing calls it, would never fire, so it gets called, probably by the framework itself. Can you post how does the minified version look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's standard minifier approach, to make code smaller it also changes variable names to smaller.

You can solve it in three ways :

a) in minifier you have to specify no to change variable names. (for example `mangle: false` in uglify plugin)

b) use an angular array notation, example :

```
angular.service(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { .... } ]);
```

c) use $inject property, example:

```
var Router = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state(home, {
            resolve:{
                myFactory: 'MyFactory',
                checkUser: function(myFactory){
                    return myFactory.getUser().then(function(data){
                    // some logic with data
                });
            }
        },
    });
};
Router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
module.exports = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', Router];
```

In your specific scenario only a) and c) will work